# Nlog health monitoring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, logging, nlog

How can I monitor the health of Nlog, means lets say nlog has failed to log the error , how I will make sure that Nlog is working perfectly?.

I know that nlog has internal error log, but I would like to notify me when nlog stopped working/

I looked into NLog documentation [NLog Docs](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial), did not find right answer

look like RetryingWrapper is a only option

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target could be an option. It will allow you to execute code when primary target fails. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target (Please don't forward to NLog Logger)

Comment: Btw. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging has `InternalLogger.LogWriter`-interface that you can hook into, and be notified on warnings/errors (Please don't forward to NLog Logger)